# How to know which shell window am I in?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, gnu-screen

I read this guide to screen https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/.

It says we can switch shell window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> followed by a number from <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd>.

Suppose I am in window #7. How do I know that? What should I `echo` to know that I am in window `7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "$WINDOW"
```

is one way; another would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>; the `*` indicates your current window and number, e.g `0` here:

```
0*$ bash  2-$ bash
```

Reference:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Environment.html